# I'm having problem installing mongoose in my project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I tried to install mongoose on my project using npm install mongoose but the terminal say..

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kimmy/.npm/_logs/2023-01-27T13_01_37_127Z-debug.log

**Here is the log error**
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/kimmy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/kimmy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.2/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'mongoose'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.17
3 info using node@v14.21.2
4 verbose npm-session 8ab7c7a226abac11
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose 105321ms
8 timing npm Completed in 139026ms
9 error cb() never called!
10 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
11 error <https://npm.community>

my nodejs version is: **v10.19.0**
my npm version is: **6.14.17**
```

I tried deleting the nodejs module and package.json.lock and reinstall npm

Comment: The current node version is 19, recommended for most users is 18, please install a newer version

Comment: update your nodejs to a newer version, if you really need this old version of node, on linux you can use nvm ( node version manager - forks available for other operating systems as well ) to have multiple versions installed, but i recommend you at least use node version 14 or 16, less than that is too old!